# How to toggle an element with on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [Hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) library for mobile touch events and in their example for use with jQuery, they have the following:

```
$('#test_el').hammer().on("tap", ".nested_el", function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
});
```

This is straightforward; however, I would like to incorporate a toggle behavior to #test_el. In other words, if the above example was replaced with something like this:

```
$('button').hammer().on("tap", function() {
    $('div').addClass('open');
}, function {
   $('div').addClass('close');
});
```

How would I get this "toggle" behavior to work?

Comment: Could use this http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, you could add a starting class to all buttons. Then on event, you can check if the class exists. This lets you know what state the element was in when you tapped it.

```
$('button').addClass('close');

$('button').hammer().on('tap', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('close')) {
    $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
    // Event code
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    // Event code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery also provides a [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a `toggleClass` function available in JQuery, it seems that it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#test_el').hammer().on("tap", ".nested_el", function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classnamehere");
});
```

Where `classnamehere` would be your class name.